# Is using a Service for sharing functions between controllers a best practice?

Tags: angularjs

I have multiple controllers that use the same functions. To keep it DRY I have tried 2 different ways of sharing the functions between controllers and am wondering what is the best practice with sharing functions:

1. Nested Controllers. Declare and add to the scope all shared functions in a parent controller, and the nested controllers call the parent function.
2. Service. Declare the shared functions in a service.

From what I have read it seems that the using a service is the best way to accomplish something like this. This works in most cases, but there are a few edge cases where I question if it makes sense to have certain logic in the service:

- Using a function in the service to modify data within the service. In the deleteNote() function I am deleting an array element from an object in the same service. Should I modify the data in a controller and then update the service?
- deleteCurrentPage() calls a different function in the same service, is this appropriate? Or should deleteCurrentPage() be declared in a controller, that then calls the service function?
- deleteCurrentPage() changes the route to a different state. For some reason this seems less than ideal. Are router/state changes appropriate to put in a service? If not, how should I approach this, do a callback instead?

TLDR: I am grappling if certain types of shared functionality belong in a service or a controller.

Thanks

Example service functions

```
  var serviceMethods = {
    currentProjectData: null,

    deleteCurrentPage: function (success, error) {
      var projectId = $stateParams.projectId,
          pageId = $stateParams.pageId;

      serviceMethods.deletePage(projectId, pageId)
      .then( function(response){
        $state.go('project.settings', {projectId: projectId});
      });
    },

    deletePage: function (projectId, pageId, success, error) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      $http.delete(constants.PROJECTS_URL + projectId + '/pages/' + pageId)
      .success(function (data) {
        serviceMethods.currentProjectData = data;
        deferred.resolve(data);
      })
      .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        error(error);
      });

      return deferred.promise;
    },

    deleteNote: function (id, success, error) {
      var index = noteIndexFromId(id),
          pageId = $stateParams.pageId;

      if (index) {
        serviceMethods.currentProjectData.pages[pageId].note.splice(index, 1);
      }
    },
```

Comment: `Is using a Service for sharing functions between controllers a best practice?` - YES. Services are singletons that you can inject to any controller and put service values in a controller's scope. Anyways, service provide  better control over where those are used and exposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, like @Maxim I believe that using a service is the way to go. Services (or models in general in the MVC pattern) were designed exactly to manage the logic layer and thus keep controllers as light as possible.

> Using a function in the service to modify data within the service. In the deleteNote()     function I am deleting an array element from an object in the same service. Should I modify     the data in a controller and then update the service?

A deleteNote method is perfectly fine but I would personally pass an object to it and retrieve the same object with the note deleted so that no data are saved in the service.

> deleteCurrentPage() calls a different function in the same service, is this appropriate? Or should deleteCurrentPage() be declared in a controller, that then calls the service function?

It's fine to call another method from the service but you should use a private method for that. Use `var deletePage = function(...)` or simply `function deletePage(...)` for that.

> deleteCurrentPage() changes the route to a different state. For some reason this seems less than ideal. Are router/state changes appropriate to put in a service? If not, how should I approach this, do a callback instead?

Sorry it's difficult to understand that question from the context.

Enjoy Angular!